# RequireJS inside Web Worker – onmessage not called

Tags: javascript, requirejs, web-worker

I've got problems using RequireJS inside a web worker especially dealing with the `onmessage` handler that is not called in the first version of *worker.js*.

**app.js**

```
var w = new Worker('worker.js');
w.postMessage(someData);

w.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log(event.data);
};
```

**worker.js** [with RequireJS – *not* working, but no errors]

```
importScripts('require.js');

require({ baseUrl: 'foo' },
    ['dependency1'],
    function(dependency1) {

        self.onmessage = function (event) { // never called
            // do something with event.data...
            self.postMessage(data);
        };

        self.postMessage('debug'); // this one works
    }
);
```

**worker.js** [without RequireJS – working]

```
onmessage = function (event) {
    // do something with event.data...
    postMessage(data);
};
```

Comment: I do not set `self`, it's given: http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/#the-global-scope & https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers (first paragraph);

about onmessage: http://html5index.org/Web%20Workers%20-%20DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope.html

Comment: I've got a hacky (?) solution, but I am not allowed to post it, yet. One could just put the `require()` method [first version] inside the `onmessage = f(e) {}` from the second version and get rid of `self.onmessage`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the web worker:

```
require({baseUrl: "../lib"},
["require","timer"], function(Timer) {
     self.onmessage = function(event) { console.log("Received"); }
     postMessage("In require");
});
```

Here's the module that invokes it:

```
var worker = new Worker('src/workers/worker.js'); 
worker.postMessage("hello"); //This fails
worker.onmessage = function(event) {
console.log(event);
};
```

However, calls from a button that postMessage to the worker succeed. I got `received` back.

Suspecting an async loading issue, I modified my code.

```
var worker = new Worker('src/workers/timer_worker.js');
   console.log(worker);
   worker.onmessage = function(event) {
       console.log(event);
       switch(event.data.message) {
           case "loaded": 
                worker.postMessage("hello");
           break;
       };
   };
```

Just have the worker dispatch a message when it finishes loading within the require model and fire off your subsequent code in response.

Edit - here's a diagram to make it clearer. The `onmessage` calls are in pink:

[image: UML sequence diagram showing web worker synchronization]

Comment: I had this very problem and solved it the same way. I edited your answer to show the dynamics in UML.